# How to run Angular2 on glassfish server?

Tags: angular

Is it possible, to run application on the glassfish server using Angular 2?
if it possible, where can i will find a more information?

I will be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1):

An Angular2 application consists of à set of files served statically:

- the ones for the application itself (HTML files, JS files compiled or not TypeScript ones)
- the ones for dependencies (Angular2, Rxjs, SystemJS, ZonesJS, Reflect Metadata, ...)

If the application deployed on your Glassfish server is able to serve static files from a folder, it's possible to integrate an Angular2 part in it. Note that this application will be loaded from the server and executed in browsers.

Most of Java Web frameworks usable in Glassfish (Restlet, Spring to quote a few) support this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i run my angular app on glassfish server.
In the tutorial, tutor used the following libraries. Will you put any another library to my application??

He used also es6-shim.js library, but i don't know why.
is it need in my project??

code of my Page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>

    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>


<script>
        System.config({
            packages: {
                app: {
                    format: 'register',
                    defaultExtension: 'js'
                }
            }       
        });
        System.import('app/boot.js')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
</head>
<body>


<articles></articles>


</body>
</html>
```